How to fix error for member operator boost lexical parser ->*
Appreciate any help. I am writing a parser which works with GCC 4.9.3 + Boost 1_55 and older but not with the higher revs of Boost (or GCC).
Error is:
error: no match for ‘operator->’ (operand types are ‘const _r1_type {aka const boost::phoenix::actorboost::spirit::attribute<1 >}’ and ‘test::my_config::value_map_t {aka std::mapstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, boost::variantstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, double, int, bool, std::vector<double, std::allocator > > >}’) _r1 -> my_config::values, qi::_1
Code is:
one_statement = ( key > lit( '=' ) > qi::int_
                      > lit( ';' ) )
    [ if_( phoenix::bind( &value_map_t::count, _r1->* &my_config::values, _1 ) )
        phoenix::bind( &insert_value, _r1, _1, _2 )
    ];


typedef boost::variant<
    std::string,
    double,
    int,
    bool,
    std::vector<double>
    > parsed_types;

typedef value_map_t is std::string<string, parsed_types>;
   value_map_t values;

qi::rule<Iterator, std::pair<std::string, config_section::parsed_types>( my_config* ), skipper_t> one_statement;

This used to compile and parse as expected.

We're gonna need more context. Meanwhile, look at avoiding semantic actions, or using more explicit ways of adapting functions (using boost::phoenix::function e.g.). I have many many answers showing the variations at your disposals. To be honest, my fingers are itching to just help you lift your old code into the 21st century. So, if you want to send me a repo link, that might actually work.

After fixing a mind-boggling amount of errors and imagining all the left-out code, here's what I think reproduces your problem. Your question should have contained this, instead: https://godbolt.org/z/cET899osh

Thank you so much. My apologies  tried simplifying the code and may have done that a bit too much.

Since c++14, std::map::count is an overloaded function: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count
This is why c++20 does not allow programs to take the address of standard library functions (see https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0551r3.pdf and Can I take the address of a function defined in standard library?). Of course, many people do, but as you have found, it will silently break code.

Before you go looking, no the new c++20 std::map::contains has the same issues https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/contains


Given the little context, I'd suggest a few simplifications.
For one, you want to parse all the value types with one rule. For second, you don't need the semantic action. If you insist, just make the check whether the key already exists part of the insert_value helper function:
static bool insert_value(my_config* cfg, std::string key, config_section::parsed_types val) {
    if (!cfg)
        return false;
    return cfg->values.emplace(std::move(key), std::move(val)).second; // makes contains(key) check redundant
}

This function will return true only if the value was actually inserted. The rule can just become:
one_statement = (key_ > '=' > value_ > ';')[px::bind(&insert_value, _r1, _1, _2)];

And avoid the whole ugly mess of invoking count or contains.
Demo Time
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

namespace config_section {
    using parsed_types = boost::variant<std::string, double, int, bool, std::vector<double>>;
} // namespace config_section

using value_map_t = std::map<std::string, config_section::parsed_types>;
struct my_config {
    value_map_t values;
};

static bool insert_value(my_config* cfg, std::string key, config_section::parsed_types val) {
    if (!cfg)
        return false;
    return cfg->values.emplace(std::move(key), std::move(val)).second; // makes contains(key) check redundant
}

namespace std { // hack for debug output
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<double> const& dd) {
        os << "{";
        for (auto sep = " "; auto d : dd)
            os << std::exchange(sep, ", ") << d;
        return os << " }";
    }
} // namespace std

int main() {
    using Iterator = std::string::const_iterator;
    using namespace qi::labels;
    using skipper_t = qi::blank_type;

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()>                             key_, string_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, config_section::parsed_types(), skipper_t> value_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<double>(), skipper_t>          vec_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, void(my_config*), skipper_t>               one_statement;
    qi::real_parser<double, qi::strict_real_policies<double>>     strict_double_{};

    key_    = qi::alpha >> +qi::char_("_a-zA-Z0-9");
    vec_    = '{' >> -(qi::double_ % ',') >> '}';
    string_ = '"' >> *('\\' >> qi::char_ | ~qi::char_('"')) >> '"';
    value_  = string_ | vec_ | qi::no_case[qi::bool_] | strict_double_ | qi::int_;

    one_statement = (key_ > '=' > value_ > ';')[px::bind(&insert_value, _r1, _1, _2)];

    my_config cfg;
    for (std::string const input :
         {
             R"(simple_int     = 42;)",
             R"(simple_true    = true;   )",
             R"(simple_false   = False;)",
             R"(simple_string  = "Hello World!"; )",
             R"(escaped_string = "Hello \"Jolly\" World!"; )",
             R"(simple_double  = 42.;)",
             R"(another_double = -inf;)",
             R"(more_double    = 4.2e3;)",
             R"(empty_vec      = {};)",
             R"(filled_vec     = { 123, 234, -4e9, +Inf, NaN, 8e-2, +0 };)",
         }) //
    {
        auto f = begin(input), l = end(input);
        std::cout << " ===== parsed: " << std::boolalpha << phrase_parse(f, l, one_statement(&cfg), qi::blank)
                  << "\n";
        if (f != l)
            std::cout << "     remaining unparsed: " << quoted(std::string(f, l)) << "\n";
    }

    for (auto& [k, v] : cfg.values) {
        std::cout << quoted(k) << "\t -> " << v << "\n";
    }
}

Printing
 ===== parsed: true
 ===== parsed: true
 ===== parsed: true
 ===== parsed: true
 ===== parsed: true
 ===== parsed: true
 ===== parsed: true
 ===== parsed: true
 ===== parsed: true
 ===== parsed: true
"another_double"     -> -inf
"empty_vec"  -> { }
"escaped_string"     -> Hello "Jolly" World!
"filled_vec"     -> { 123, 234, -4e+09, inf, nan, 0.08, 0 }
"more_double"    -> 4200
"simple_double"  -> 42
"simple_false"   -> false
"simple_int"     -> 42
"simple_string"  -> Hello World!
"simple_true"    -> true

BONUS: Without Phoenix/Semantic Actions
Like I said, you don't need any of that. That's because insert will also not overwrite existing values. So, simplify even further:
Live ON Coliru
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

namespace config_section {
    using parsed_types = boost::variant<std::string, double, int, bool, std::vector<double>>;
} // namespace config_section

using value_map_t = std::map<std::string, config_section::parsed_types>;
struct my_config {
    value_map_t values;
};

namespace std { // hack for debug output
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<double> const& dd) {
        os << "{";
        for (auto sep = " "; auto d : dd)
            os << std::exchange(sep, ", ") << d;
        return os << " }";
    }
} // namespace std

template <typename Iterator> struct ConfigSection : qi::grammar<Iterator, value_map_t()> {
    ConfigSection() : ConfigSection::base_type(start) {
        key_          = qi::alpha >> +qi::char_("_a-zA-Z0-9");
        vec_          = '{' >> -(qi::double_ % ',') >> '}';
        string_       = '"' >> *('\\' >> qi::char_ | ~qi::char_('"')) >> '"';
        value_        = string_ | vec_ | qi::no_case[qi::bool_] | strict_double_ | qi::int_;
        one_statement = key_ > '=' > value_ > ';';
        config_       = *one_statement;

        start = qi::skip(qi::space)[config_ > qi::eoi];
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, value_map_t()> start;

    using Entry     = std::pair<std::string, config_section::parsed_types>;
    using skipper_t = qi::space_type;
    qi::rule<Iterator, value_map_t(), skipper_t>                  config_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, config_section::parsed_types(), skipper_t> value_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<double>(), skipper_t>          vec_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Entry(), skipper_t>                        one_statement;

    // lexemes
    qi::real_parser<double, qi::strict_real_policies<double>> strict_double_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()>                         key_, string_;
};

int main() {
    static ConfigSection<std::string::const_iterator> const parser;

    std::string const input = R"(
        simple_int     = 42;
        simple_true    = true;
        simple_false   = False;
        simple_string  = "Hello World!";
        escaped_string = "Hello \"Jolly\" World!";
        simple_double  = 42.;
        another_double = -inf;
        more_double    = 4.2e3;
        empty_vec      = {};
        filled_vec     = { 123, 234, -4e9, +Inf, NaN, 8e-2, +0 };
        simple_int     = "WILL IT BLEND?"; )"; // simple_int not overwritten

    my_config cfg;
    std::cout << " ===== parsed: " << std::boolalpha //
              << parse(begin(input), end(input), parser, cfg.values) << "\n";

    for (auto& [k, v] : cfg.values)
        std::cout << quoted(k) << "\t -> " << v << "\n";
}

Printing
 ===== parsed: true
"another_double"     -> -inf
"empty_vec"  -> { }
"escaped_string"     -> Hello "Jolly" World!
"filled_vec"     -> { 123, 234, -4e+09, inf, nan, 0.08, 0 }
"more_double"    -> 4200
"simple_double"  -> 42
"simple_false"   -> false
"simple_int"     -> 42
"simple_string"  -> Hello World!
"simple_true"    -> true


That was awesome! Thanks so much for your help and pointers. The updated code works great.
